# How to synchronize two Angular Material paginators?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have on my design page two paginator.
When I add two paginators - their data is not synchronized.
https://material.angular.io/components/paginator

https://plnkr.co/edit/w5ZuXnfIgmKW1nWgyf3Y?p=preview

```
<mat-paginator [length]="length"
               [pageSize]="10">
</mat-paginator>

<mat-paginator [length]="length"
              [pageSize]="10">
</mat-paginator>
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Have you tried `(page)="pageEvent = $event; pageSize = $event.pageSize">`? https://plnkr.co/edit/VTDeBomvc1P6il44VpUq?p=preview

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may be an old question, still found a now-working solution to this:

```html
<mat-paginator #paginatorTop 
               [length]="length"
               [pageSize]="10"
                (page)="paginatorBottom.pageIndex = $event.pageIndex">
</mat-paginator>

<mat-paginator #paginatorBottom 
              [length]="length"
              [pageSize]="10"
              (page)="paginatorTop.pageIndex = $event.pageIndex">
</mat-paginator>
```

Maybe this still helps someone